# iOS 5 - Rails 3 server - Shared key

Tags: objective-c, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, ios5

I have an iOS 5 App that consumes webservices from a Rails 3 server. One of the requirements of the application is that all the communication App -> Server -> must be encrypted by some sort of shared key.

That shared key should be used to sign all the messages sent from and to the server, so only the other side can decrypt it.

I am so lost on this topic and need some help.
Any guidelines? Any gems? iOS framework? Example?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a great article on this topic: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Amazon uses this kind of approach.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how this can avoid an attacker who sees the parameters and the checksum and invokes exactly the same request.

Comment: I will use this approach. The answer to my comment is to use a timestamp in the parameters.